# Call graphql API when the user clicks everytime on a link in UI in React js, call

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-hooks, react-redux

I have a link in React UI, clicking on that link pass a value and based on that value API is called and pdf will be generated, code is given below:

````
 ```const [pdfBlob, setPdfBlob] = useState<Blob | null>(null);
  const [pdfUrl, setPdfUrl] = useState<string | null>(null);
  const [headerSkValue, setHeaderSkValue] = useState<number | null>(null);

 
  const { data, error, refetch } = useGetInvoicePdfQuery({
    query: invoicePdfQuery,
    variables: {
      hdrSk: headerSkValue || null,
    },
  });
    const handleInvoiceNumClick = async(hdrSk: any) => {
      console.log(hdrSk);
      setHeaderSkValue(hdrSk)
      await refetch();
    if (data) {
      const decodedPdfData = window.atob(data);
      const byteArray = new Uint8Array(decodedPdfData.length);
      for (let i = 0; i < decodedPdfData.length; i++) {
        byteArray[i] = decodedPdfData.charCodeAt(i);
      }
      const pdfBlob = new Blob([byteArray.buffer], { type: 'application/pdf' });
      setPdfBlob(pdfBlob);
      const pdfUrl = URL.createObjectURL(pdfBlob)
      setPdfUrl(pdfUrl);

       if(headerSkValue !==null) {
        window.open(pdfUrl, '_blank');
      }
    }
  }```
````

HtML is as given below

`<span className='text-brand w-full text-sm px-3 cursor-pointer truncate' onClick={() => handleInvoiceNumClick(invoiceList.alwncInvcHdrSk)}>`

Now on first click 'hdrSk' value is passed as null in API payload, second time its working as expected. When trying to pass 'hdrSk' in  await refetch({hdrSk}); throwing an error -Expected 0 arguments, but got 1.

So please help me in solving this issue.